# What should be the output of cli --dry-run?

Tags: command-line, posix

Is there any expectation on the output of a command-line application's `--dry-run` option? Is a free-form human-readable explanation ok, or should it be parseable? Should it be what would be printed during a real execution? What if the real execution is quiet?

Is there any standard for this?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not codified anywhere. For a program which normally doesn't print anything, perhaps enable debugging output so the user can see what it's doing.

In this day and age, an *option* to produce machine-readable output (JSON or whatever) would always be nice. Mankind has spent way too much time reverse-engineering parsers for unspecified ad-hoc formats.